# Production build is not happening neither it is giving any errors

Tags: webpack, jhipster, webpack-dev-server

I have created a project with the jhipster and a few months back I have stopped using the prod build and was using the development builds but they are too expensive in terms of space on server and performance is too slow ....I am building something where the production build is not happening So to make the application work flowless and smooth I am trying to run prod build.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my webpack.prod.js

```
/**
 * Production config for the app.
 */
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'production';
const extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin(`assets/css/[name].[hash].css`);
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin(`assets/[name].[hash].css`);

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
    // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build.
    // You have to enable it in UglifyJSPlugin config below and in tsconfig-aot.json as well
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills',
        global: './src/assets/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main',
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('./../../public/app'),
        publicPath: 'app/',
        filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js',
        pathinfo: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                use: ['@ngtools/webpack']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
                use: extractSASS.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                use: extractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader'],
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        },
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    ie8: false,
                    // sourceMap: true, // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build
                    compress: {
                        dead_code: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        properties: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        conditionals: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        toplevel: true,
                        if_return: true,
                        inline: true,
                        join_vars: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false,
                        indent_level: 2
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractSASS,
        extractCSS,
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: [
                'en',
                'es'
            ]
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            platform: 0,
            mainPath: utils.root('./src/main.ts'),
            tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
            sourceMap: true,
            skipCodeGeneration: true,
            compilerOptions: {}
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true,
        })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
});
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "Harshit-demo",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "a demo project ",
"private": true,
"cacheDirectories": [
"node_modules"
],
"engines": {
"node": ">=8.11.3",
"yarn": ">=1.7.0"
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"IE 11"
],
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/router": "^7.2.12",
"@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
"@types/html2canvas": "0.0.35",
"@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
"angular-laravel-echo": "^2.1.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.6.3",
"html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
"jspdf": "^1.5.3",
"laravel-echo": "^1.4.1",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.15",
"ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
"ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.9",
"ngx-cookie": "4.0.2",
"ngx-filesaver": "^2.1.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
"tslib": "1.9.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.3",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/language-service": "^7.2.12",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
"@types/node": "^10.14.4",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"browser-sync": "^2.26.0",
"browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
"cache-loader": "^1.2.5",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
"css-loader": "^1.0.1",
"del-cli": "^1.1.0",
"exports-loader": "0.7.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"file-loader": "^1.1.11",
"fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "0.4.1",
"friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
"hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.12.0",
"html-loader": "0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
"husky": "0.14.3",
"image-webpack-loader": "^4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"lint-staged": "7.0.0",
"merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.14",
"moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.0.5",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3",
"postcss-loader": "2.1.1",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"rimraf": "2.6.1",
"sass-loader": "7.0.1",
"simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
"style-loader": "0.20.3",
"tapable": "1.0.0",
"thread-loader": "1.1.5",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"ts-loader": "4.0.1",
"ts-node": "5.0.1",
"tslint": "^5.12.1",
"tslint-config-prettier": "1.9.0",
"tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
"webdriver-manager": "^12.1.0",
"webpack": "4.8.2",
"webpack-cli": "2.1.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.10",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
"webpack-notifier": "1.6.0",
"webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.4.1",
"write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
"xml2js": "0.4.19"
},
"resolutions": {},
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"clean:cache": "yarn cache clean",
"clean": "rimraf ../../public/app/*",
"build:dev": "yarn run webpack:dev",
"build:prod": "yarn run webpack:prod",
"serve": "yarn run webpack:dev-run",
"lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
"lint:fix": "yarn run lint --fix",
"protractor": "protractor test/protractor.conf.js",
"e2e": "protractor test/protractor.conf.js",
"test": "yarn run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config test/javascript/jest.conf.js",
"test:watch": "yarn test --watch --clearCache",
"webpack:dev-run": "yarn run webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
"webpack:dev": "yarn run clean && yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=normal",
"webpack:prod": "yarn run clean && yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js",
"webpack-dev-server": "node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
}
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. It's also not clear how you run your prod build, using mvnw or gradlew? It's aslo unfortunate that you abandoned exact versions for your dependencies in package.json asx they originally were when generated by JHipster.

Comment: does `./mvnw verify -Pprod -DskipTests` gives you any error?  as @GaëlMarziou states, it's not clear what the issue is